# Multiple Addthis buttons on the same page with absolute position only shows the first one

Tags: css, addthis

so I have 3 boxes each box we have small share button that will sit in the top right of the box, (absolute css position).

Addthis will only show when hovering on the first one, if css absolute is taken out then it will work in all boxes. I've tried setting absolute on the actually sharethis element as well as putting it inside an absolute container.  Neither works. I could not find an example on the addthis website.

This is the absolute container I tried around addthis, this div is inside the larger div

[image]
                        
    

   some content

```
<style>
```

.promotionItem { position:relative; }

```
#promotionsSlider .shareContainer {
 width: 30px;
 height: 29px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 display: block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Seems likely that you have forgotten to add `position:relative` to the parent element **but** without a demo it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Sorry I did not add all the code, yes parent has that property. The issue is not positioning, the issue is Addthis doesn't work correctly, it will only show on the first box with absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Your positioning all your share buttons on top of one another, by using absolute position they won't respect each other's position in the Dom... You'll need to give each a left or vertical absolute position depending on where you want them to sit.

Below I'm presuming you have 3 icons you want to position and I'm aligning these horizontally.

```
#promotionsSlider .shareContainer {
 width: 30px;
 height: 29px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 display: block;
}

#promotionsSlider .shareContainer:nth-of-type(2) {
 right: 40px;
}

#promotionsSlider .shareContainer:nth-of-type(3) {
 right: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou I clarified the code a little, the issue is not positioning, the issue is Addthis.com does not work with 'absolute'